# SSIS package is showing successful but not performing action in any task

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have one job where after taking backup of data mart in 2nd step a ssis pkg is calling (performing delta load) but the weird situation is that this package is showing successful from last two months everyday but without loading/trucating/updating data in the package.

It just touching all the task without doing anything and make this step successful within some 1-3 minute(normally this step of job takes around 2-3 hours).

I have checked all the permissions and access to sa and all are fine.

The local configuration tables are also fine.

Could you please suggest what could be the reason for this and where I need to investigate the issue. (It's a production server.)

Comment: Check the Windows Application Event Log for errors. Are you sure the deployed Package does not have Steps disabled, so it's only validating? Are you sure it uses the Production configuration and doesn't connect to a test/dev environment with small amounts of data?

Comment: Have you checked all the "Am I being an idiot" settings yet?  Such as: is your SSIS package pulling data from the right place or a static test database?  If *absolutely everything* works as it should, what happens when you follow the process through in Visual Studio?  Does it run as expected?